# MDX query in cube calculation

Tags: ssas, mdx

I've created a simple cube calculation that sums two measures.I only want to sum, or to return data when both measures return a value.

When I use the calculation in an MDX query, it works as expected, however when I browse the cube via a pivot table I it display all results, and not what I need. It seems to me that I need to modify the cube calculation to get the same NONEMPTY behaviour as per the MDX query, but I just can't get the syntax correct, or know if this is indeed the correct approach. I'd be grateful for some pointers.

[image: MDX Query]

Sample of underlying data:

[image: Underlying data]

Cube calculation:

[image: Simple addition of two measures]

This MDX statement does exactly what I want it to:

[image: MDX query result as required]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/iif-mdx) function would be useful in this scenario

For e.g.,

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[RevalCombined]
AS IIF([Measures].[Reval]=0, NULL, [Measures].[Reval]) + IIF([Measures].[dReval]=0, NULL, [Measures].[dReval])
```